# Некорректный вывод в html

Tags: html, golang

Есть код html

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>   
        <tr>

            <td>{{.IdU}}</td>
            <td>{{.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{.SecName}}</td>
        
            <td>{{.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{.Company}}</td>
            <td>{{.Model}}</td>
            <td>{{.Price}}</td>
            <br>
        </tr>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

И код golang

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Names struct {
    IdU     int
    Name    string
    SecName string
    Id      int
    Company string
    Model   string
    Price   int
}

var dbpath string = "host=192.168.1.103 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=phones sslmode=disable password=mypass"

func GetNames() {
    http.HandleFunc("/data", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dbpath)
        defer db.Close()
        rows, _ := db.Query("select * from Names")
        rowsp, _ := db.Query("select * from Products")
        defer rows.Close()
        defer rowsp.Close()
        names := []Names{}

        for rows.Next() || rowsp.Next() {
            n := Names{}
            rows.Scan(&n.IdU, &n.Name, &n.SecName)
            rowsp.Scan(&n.Id, &n.Company, &n.Model, &n.Price)
            names = append(names, n)
        }

        for _, n := range names {
            names := Names{
                IdU:     n.IdU,
                Name:    n.Name,
                SecName: n.SecName,
                Id:      n.Id,
                Company: n.Company,
                Model:   n.Model,
                Price:   n.Price,
            }
            templn, _ := template.ParseFiles("./user.html")
            templn.Execute(w, names)
        }

    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}
func main() {
    GetNames()
}
```

Вместе они должны выводить на страницу html на сервере данные из таблицы базы postgresql. И они это делают но вывод получается некорректный.
Вот такой

```
1 Maksim Donets 0 0
2 Maksim Pupkin 0 0
0 1 Iphone XR Apple 44000
0 2 Iphone SE Apple 29000
0 3 AirPods Pro Apple 11000
0 4 AirDods 2 Pro Xiaomi 5000
0 5 Note 9 Pro Xiaomi 25000
0 6 6300 Nokia 5000
```

В конце 1 и 2 строк и в начале всех следующих есть нули. Их быть не должно. Подскажите пожалуйста как из убрать?
Данные в базе такие.[данные в базе](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTAqk.jpg)

Comment: покажите что в таблице лежит

Comment: @SeniorPomidor добавил скрин

Answer (score 0):

все это можно упростить и сделать 1 выборку из базы вместо двух. Вам все равно меджить их надо в одну.

в темплейте нужно указывать `{{range .}}` и передать массив данных, а не 1 экземпляр `Names`

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Names struct {
    IdU     int
    Name    string
    SecName string
    Id      int
    Company string
    Model   string
    Price   int
}

var dbpath string = "host=192.168.1.103 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=phones sslmode=disable password=mypass"

func GetNames() {
    http.HandleFunc("/data", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dbpath)
        defer db.Close()

        rows, _ := db.QueryContext(r.Context(),`select n.*, p.* from "Names" n, "Products" p;`)
        defer rows.Close()

        names := []Names{}

        for rows.Next(){
            n := Names{}
            err := rows.Scan(&n.IdU, &n.Name, &n.SecName, &n.Id, &n.Company, &n.Model, &n.Price)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            fmt.Printf("%#v\n", n)
            names = append(names, n)
        }

        templn, err := template.ParseFiles("/tmp/user.html")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        err = templn.Execute(w, names)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

    })

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
func main() {
    GetNames()
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    {{range .}}
    <tr>

        <td>{{.IdU}}</td>
        <td>{{.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{.SecName}}</td>

        <td>{{.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{.Company}}</td>
        <td>{{.Model}}</td>
        <td>{{.Price}}</td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

вывод

```
1 Maksim Donets 1 Iphone XR Apple 44000
1 Maksim Donets 2 Iphone SE Apple 29000
1 Maksim Donets 3 AirPods Pro Apple 11000
1 Maksim Donets 4 AirDods 2 Pro Xiaomi 5000
1 Maksim Donets 5 Note 9 Pro Xiaomi 25000
1 Maksim Donets 6 6300 Nokia 5000
2 Maksim Pipkin 1 Iphone XR Apple 44000
2 Maksim Pipkin 2 Iphone SE Apple 29000
2 Maksim Pipkin 3 AirPods Pro Apple 11000
2 Maksim Pipkin 4 AirDods 2 Pro Xiaomi 5000
2 Maksim Pipkin 5 Note 9 Pro Xiaomi 25000
2 Maksim Pipkin 6 6300 Nokia 5000
```